# как работает магия Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

В официальной документации Symfony, есть такие примеры как

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

public function index(SessionInterface $session)
{
    // stores an attribute for reuse during a later user request
    $session->set('foo', 'bar');

    // gets the attribute set by another controller in another request
    $foobar = $session->get('foobar');

    // uses a default value if the attribute doesn't exist
    $filters = $session->get('filters', []);
}
```

Я хочу узнать как это работает, что если передать как аргумент функции Interface, то при ее вызове функции получит его автоматически. 
Хочу применить это в проекте который изначально, к сожалению, был написан без фреймворка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не так давно я сам задавал такой вопрос. В **PHP** есть такое понятие как *Рефлексия*, вот цитата из Википедии.

> В информатике отражение или рефлексия (холоним интроспекции, англ.
>   reflection) означает процесс, во время которого программа может
>   отслеживать и модифицировать собственную структуру и поведение во время выполнения. — [Wikipedia.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Говоря на простом языке, программа анализирует сама себя и перед тем как вызвать метод контроллера она смотрит на входные параметры и если находит пытается *зарезолвить*. Откуда она их берет? Из контейнера свойств.

Все это можно написать самому но нужны хорошие знания ООП и шаблонов проектирования.

Такой подход реализован у многих фреймворках включая *Symfony* и *Laravel*

Вот вам некоторые ссылки по которым я делал нечто похожее:

Официальна документация раздела [Reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.reflection.php) на сайте php.net

Статья на Хабре [Введение в PHP Reflection API](https://habr.com/ru/post/433266/)

Статья [Что такое внедрение зависимостей в PHP](https://myrusakov.ru/php-dependency-injection.html)

Это довольно обширный вопрос и вместить все в один ответ просто не получится, он тянет как минимум на целую статью с ссылками на источники для дальнейшего изучения. А это я так просто пальцем указал в каком направлении двигаться.

Comment: @Алексей Семянников однако если вы захотите внедрить у себя данную историю, вам стоит использовать уже готовые компоненты Symfony в своем проекте. Пытаться соорудить своё - так себе идея.

Comment: @zalex попытки разобраться и создать собственный контейнер, приведут к углубленному изучению паттернов проектирования и понимания их принципа работы. Разобравшись в этом деле придет понимание как, зачем и почему. После этого использовать готовые решения будет намного проще. Для реального нагруженного проекта, да, возможно не самое лучшее решение.

Answer (score 1):

Эту магию делает `Service Container` и в частности `autowiring`. Ежели раньше нужно было зависимости  брать непосредственно из контейнера, в случае с Контроллером либо описвать в services если вы описываете зависимости для сервиса, то начиная с версии 3.4 ServiceContainer умеет делать эту самую магию. Никто лучше официальной документации наврядли вам объяснит, а посмотреть это можно например [тут](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/autowiring.html#autowiring-logic-explained) да и вообще стоит прочитать всю эту страницу.